# Why does write print weird characters for int/double type?

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double s = 43;
    write(1, &s, sizeof(double));
}
```

This is the output : �E@

```
int num = 1234;
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &num, sizeof(num));
```

I have the same issue too, output : �

Comment: It is printing the bytes your `double` is consisting of. What else would you expect?

Comment: because it is binary data.  If you want to write the data as text, use printf or similar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you think should be printed instead? Why?

Comment: If you wanted to see a numeric representation that approximates what you would envision a `double` value to look like,  eg. `43.00000`, then you could prepare a string buffer and use `sprintf(buf, "%0.5f", 43);`, to populate buf with a floating point looking variable, then use  `write(stdout, buf, sizeof buf);` to send it to `stdout`.

Comment: For more fun, try `int num = 12345;`.  The file ends up containing the characters `90`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` does not convert the value to text before writing it. What you are doing is writing the binary value of the double to a file.

You should convert it to a string before, like so :

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double s = 43;
    char buff[26]; //Buffer to store the string
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%f", s); //Convert the float to a string
    write(1, &s, strlen(buff));
}
```

Note the use of [snprintf](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/). It works like printf, but writes to an array instead. [sprintf](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) would also work but can be unsafe as there are no limit to the number of characters written, which can cause segmentation faults.

Comment: Could use `char buff[26];  snprintf(buff, sizeof buf, "%.17g", s);` to print all `double` distinctively without overfilling `buf[]`.